# How to create search boxes to spit out the results from a database

Tags: php, html

I am creating a result page using php to pull data from database. 
I have been able to connect the database to my webspace and displayed the data.

Now , I would like to have the page not show all the data at once. I want to add an input field example "Origen= Los Angeles" "Destination = London"  and then show the results based on that criteria.

This is my first time doing something like this so if this sounds like I should know this I'm sorry. I hope I can get some help.

```
<?php

   // include connection settings
   require_once "connect.php";

    // display a list of flights
    if(!empty($_GET) && !empty($_GET['name'])){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Flight_Information WHERE name LIKE ''".
            $_GET['name']."".$_GET['name']."'";
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT ID, airlineName, departureAirport, departureDate, destinationAirport FROM Flight_Information";
    } // END if

    $result = $db->query($query);
    if ($result) {
        // ... display results in while loop
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<li><a href="FindaFriendShip.php?Flight_Information_ID='.$row['ID'].'">'.$row['airlineName'].' '.$row['departureAirport'].''.$row['departureDate'].''.$row['destinationAirport'].'</a></li>';
        } // END while
    } else {
        // if there was an error with your query
        // this will display it
        echo "SQL Error: " . $db->error;
    } // END if
?>
  </ul>

<?php


    if (!empty($_GET) && !empty($_GET['Flight_Information_ID'])) {


      $Flight_Information_ID = $_GET['Flight_Information_ID'];


      $query = "SELECT * FROM Flight_Information WHERE ID =" . $Flight_Information_ID;

      // perform the query
      if ($result = $db->query($query)) {

        // check we have a result
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

          // loop through and print out the results
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            // output a title for each result
            echo '<hr/><p>You have selected FriendShipper' .$Flight_Information_ID. ':</p> <ul>';

            // loop through and output details for each item
            foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
              echo '<li><em>'.$key.'</em> = <strong>'.$value.'</strong></li>';
            }

            // output a horizontal rule under the result
            echo '</ul><hr/>';
          }

        // num_rows = 0, no results found
        } else {
          echo "<p>No Flights Found " .$Flight_Information_ID. "</p>";
        }

      // if there was an error with your query, this will display it
      } else {
        echo "SQL Error: " . $db->error;
      }
    }


?>
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  What is the result of your current code?  You are expected to make an attempt to accomplish your task yourself first, not just tell us what you want it to do so that we can do it for you.  If there is something _specific_ that is not working as you expect it to, _that_ is where we can come in and help, as long as you provide the necessary details.

Comment: Patric, Thanks for responding. I am 3 months new at this, I am taking a webapps class that focused on HTML, and CSS and I am just trying to learn more about the back end of webapps and I am teaching myself. I created fake data on phpMyadmin I wanted to learn about databases. Like I mention I have been able to connect to my database and run a query to pull the data from my database to my site. I have tried to displayed the data on a table, but I haven't been successful. Like you mention I know how I want the page to behave but I just don't know where to start. Any reading recommendations?

Comment: Honestly, just start at Google and go from there (personally I'd suggest avoiding results from w3schools, others may feel differently).  Without knowing the specifics of where you're stuck, it's hard to give suggestions.  Additionally, requesting 3rd party resources, guides, tutorials, etc is off-topic here and is one of the reasons why a question can be closed.

Comment: Welcome! To add to what Patrick is saying, it will be helpful to have a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue you're facing. It sounds like it'll be difficult to do in your case because you've got a couple of different technologies interacting, including reading from a database that probably isn't easily accessible to us. But doing that will make it easier for people to give helpful answers. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much!